# Literal String With Mixed Variables

Tags: javascript

This does not work and I get a JavaScript error stating that I am missing a ;. Is there a better way I should be mixing variables with HTML?

```
var video_html = '<video id="video-tag" width="640" height="480" poster="' + filePath + fileImage + '" controls="controls" preload="none">\
  <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->\
  <source id="source-mp4" type="video/mp4" src="' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />\
  <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->\
  <source id="source-webm" type="video/webm" src="' + filePath + fileWebM + '" />\
  <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->\
  <object width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">\
      <param name="movie" value="build/flashmediaelement.swf" />\
      <param id="flashvars-param" name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=' + filePath + fileImage '&file=' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />\
      <!-- Image as a last resort -->\
      <img id="fallback-image" src="' + filePath + fileImage + '" width="640" height="480" title="No video playback capabilities" />\
  </object>\
  </video>';
```

I'm eventually doing something like this with it.

`$("#video-wrap").empty().append(video_html);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
<param id="flashvars-param" name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=' + filePath + fileImage '&file=' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />\
```

needs to be:

```
<param id="flashvars-param" name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=' + filePath + fileImage + '&file=' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />\
```

You are missing a `+`

Entire Example:

```
var video_html = '<video id="video-tag" width="640" height="480" poster="' + filePath + fileImage + '" controls="controls" preload="none">\
  <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->\
  <source id="source-mp4" type="video/mp4" src="' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />\
  <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->\
  <source id="source-webm" type="video/webm" src="' + filePath + fileWebM + '" />\
  <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->\
  <object width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">\
      <param name="movie" value="build/flashmediaelement.swf" />\
      <param id="flashvars-param" name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=' + filePath + fileImage + '&file=' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />\
      <!-- Image as a last resort -->\
      <img id="fallback-image" src="' + filePath + fileImage + '" width="640" height="480" title="No video playback capabilities" />\
  </object>\
  </video>';
```

Comment: I figured it was something ridiculous. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to create an HTML snippet with a few replaced values.  Since you're already using jQuery an ideal solution is a jQuery template

- http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

The template

```
<script id="theTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <video id="video-tag" width="640" height="480" poster="${imagePath}" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
    <source id="source-mp4" type="video/mp4" src="' + filePath + fileMP4 + '" />
    <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->\
    <source id="source-webm" type="video/webm" src="' + filePath + fileWebM + '" />
    <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
    <object width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
      <param name="movie" value="build/flashmediaelement.swf" />
      <param id="flashvars-param" name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster='${imagePath}'&file='${mp4Path}'" />
      <!-- Image as a last resort -->\
      <img id="fallback-image" src="${imagePath}" width="640" height="480" title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>
  </video>
</script>
```

The JavaScript

```
var args = {
  imagePath = filePath + fileImage,
  mp4Path = filePath + fileMP4
};
var theHtml = $('#theTemplate').tmpl(args);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I had never heard of jQuery templates.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever mix HTML with JavaScript code. Use templates instead, there are a lot of them available and even very tiny and simple ones.

Examples:

- [jQuery tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)
- [jQote2](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote2/)
- [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- ...